# Highlight DataGrid column header when mouse overing

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

If I set `CanUserSort` to `false` in a `DataGridTextColumn` (or in a `DataGridTemplateColumn`) because I want to do the sorting manually, when I place the mouse over the  column header, it doesn't highlight anymore.

Here are both examples:

[image: Both examples]

**How can I force that behaviour?**

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 2 ways:

1. Set CanUserSort to True but canel sorting on Sorting event of the datagrid by:

   e.Handled = true;
2. Retemplate DataGridColumnHeader - add mouseover trigger to highlight header.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already knew 1), in fact, I changed my code a few minutes after I posted the question to use that approach. What I don't know is how to do it using the 2nd way you propose. How exactly can I *highlight* the header?

Answer (score 1):

As per Microsoft documentation, when the **DataGridHeaderBorder.IsClickable** property is  `false`, the hover appearance will not be applied, even when **DataGridHeaderBorder.IsHovered** value is `true` ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windows.themes.datagridheaderborder.isclickable?view=netframework-4.7.2)). So in order to keep the hover appearance, the **IsClickable** property must be `true`.

The default style of the **DataGridColumnHeader** uses a template binding which binds its **IsClickable** property to the **CanUserSort** property of the column. So if you wish to maintain the hover appearance using the default style, you must set **CanUserSort** = `true` in order to make **IsClickable** = `true`. However, if you don't want to allow user sorting, then using the default style is probably not the best option.

One way to solve the problem is to use a *modified style* for the **DataGridColumnHeader**. You can take a copy of the default style and adjust how the **IsClickable** property is set. Instead of making **IsClickable** dependent on **CanUserSort**, it can be set directly to `true`. This allows the hover appearance to persist even when user sorting is disabled. The XAML for the modified style is as follows:

```
<Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderGripperStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="8"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Grid>
                    <Themes:DataGridHeaderBorder BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                 BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                 Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                                 IsClickable="True"
                                                 IsPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"
                                                 IsHovered="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                                 Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                 SortDirection="{TemplateBinding SortDirection}"
                                                 SeparatorBrush="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}"
                                                 SeparatorVisibility="{TemplateBinding SeparatorVisibility}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Themes:DataGridHeaderBorder>
                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Make sure you reference the "Themes" namespace in your XAML as follows:

```
xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
```

Finally, wherever you define the **DataGridColumn**, make sure to reference this style such as the following:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}"/>
```

Comment: This answer deserves +500 pts!